# Unexpected value for argument 'function' when using GLib introspection

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk2

From this (boiled down) test program:

```
from gi.repository import GLib

def on_timer1(tmr):
    print "Here we are"
    return False

def main(args):
    tmr1 = GLib.timeout_add(800, on_timer1)
    GLib.MainLoop.run()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Error invoking GLib.timeout_add: Unexpected value for
>   argument 'function'

I found plenty of examples to code which uses `import glib` (i.e. no introspection) which uses just this syntax. None *with* introspection though.
I also found [a reference to a similar error message](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=639318) for `idle_add`, which turned out to be a bug.

Questions
1. What is the correct syntax to get the above working?
2. Is there some system/documentation of the actual syntax of, eg. GLib names using introspection?

**Update**: Well, it might not be related to the repository. I was doing another program:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

def main(args):
    x = np.arange(0, 1, 100)
    y1 = x^2

    pyplot.plot(x, y1)

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

and got the error I hinted at above:

> ```
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gi/types.py", line 44, in
> function
> return info.invoke(*args) TypeError: Error invoking GLib.timeout_add: Unexpected value for argument 'function'
> ```

So the issue may not be related to introspection after all (I'm removing the tag).

Comment: What do you mean by "introspection" here? You're using it in a different way than I've seen it used before.

Comment: Well, unless I'm very mistaken, I'm importing the accesses to the `glib` library from the `gi` repository (Gnome Introspection). I've been using this for years now with Gtk. Mind, I'm always up for corrections :) Lately, I've seen a few versions which do `import gi.repository.GLib` though I suspect it's equivalent

Comment: Ah, so it's a kind of magic module that automatically installs stuff if you don't already have it? Personally I would just eschew the magic and install what I need the regular way.

Comment: Well, it's more magical than that. The old way was to use a wrapper around the libraries - one each for pygtk, glib etc. That meant a lot of work each time when the original library changed. Using introspection, you can *directly* access those libraries, not only in Python, but every language which has the introspection interface. It uses .gir files which describe the interface. I can't imagine much people willing to continue the wrapper work. I hope I explained this right. I'm not fully comfortable with the inner workings of system.